# How to convert byte array into integer value

Tags: java, hex

I have stored an integer value into 4 bytes and I have trouble converting it back into integer.

```
byte[] pom = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(60000).array();
```

In each byte I have an hexadecimal part of my int number.

```
arr[0] = 0
arr[1] = 0
arr[2] = ea
arr[3] = 60
```

How can I convert it back into integer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use [`ByteBuffer.getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt--):

```
int pomAsInt = ByteBuffer.wrap(pom).getInt();
```